# Why are group by operations considered expensive in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can anyone explain me how jobs are mapped and reduces in hadoop and why are group by operations considered expensive?

Comment: Who is considering them expensive?

Answer (score 0):

I won't say expensive really. But I would use the word that it does affect the performance, as for order by or sort the processing needed to order the record is much more. The processing of data by comparator and partitioner would be huge when millions or billions of records are being sorted.

I hope I could answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Performance in Hadoop is affected by two main factors:

1- Processing: The execution time spent for processing the map and reduce tasks over the cluster node.

2- Communication: Shuffling data, Some operations needs to send data from one node to another one for processing (like global sorting).

Groupby needs complexity needs affects the two factors. In the shuffle half of the data size might be shuffled between the nodes.